# How to put a query in CursorLoader format?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-cursorloader

This is query, `select * from triphistory  where    _startdate  BETWEEN   '2014-12-11 17:52:0'  AND '2014-12-17 17:52:0'`

I tried  this:

```
c = new CursorLoader(this,
                    HollaContractClass.Hollas.TRIP_HISTORY_URI,
                    PROJECTION,
                    HollaContractClass.Hollas.HollaTripHistoryColumns.START_DATE
                    + "  BETWEEN  '"+ startDate+" AND "+ endDate+"'",
                    new String[] {},
                    HollaContractClass.Hollas.HollaTripHistoryColumns.START_DATE
                    + " asc");
```

but it is not working how can I get it done?

Comment: "Not working" is hardly a good problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some single quotes here:

```
+ "  BETWEEN  '"+ startDate+" AND "+ endDate+"'",
```

Should be

```
+ "  BETWEEN  '"+ startDate+"' AND '"+ endDate+"'",
```

But do consider using argument binding instead:

```
+ "  BETWEEN ? AND ?",
new String[] { startDate, endDate },
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i solve this by     c = new CursorLoader(
    this,
    HollaContractClass.Hollas.TRIP_HISTORY_URI,
    PROJECTION,
       HollaContractClass.Hollas.HollaTripHistoryColumns.START_DATE
      + "  BETWEEN  '"+ startDate+"' AND '"+ endDate+"'",
    new String[] {},
    HollaContractClass.Hollas.HollaTripHistoryColumns.START_DATE
      + " asc");